# Applying Regression to Optimization (Rather than Applying Optimization to Regression)?

Tags: optimization, regression

My original question didn't generate the response I was looking for, so I'm going to ask a new but more specific question.

Let's say that we compute parameters for a multiple linear regression model for a data set, which includes at least one quadratic term.

If we were to collapse the first degree and second degree terms for a single variable and then compute the argmin (or argmax) for that variable, would there be any theoretical problems with this approach?

Comment: this is done already, see [these papers](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=neural+network+for+optimization)

Comment: I don't follow the relevance of your link. It returns a list of documents relating to neural networks. I don't know much about neural networks but I've always regarded them as black box methods. I can't see any obvious connection to standard-ish forms of regression, which in general, involve a well defined predictor function, which in turn would lead to a well defined objective function.

Comment: If you are concerned by regression, you **must** be concerned by optimization. If you are concerned by optimization, you do not even need to know what is a regression.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. I'm not sure what you mean by "concerned", do you mean "interested in"? In which case I would have to disagree with you. Many people are trained in regression without being trained in optimization. And you your second statement, seems to suggest that if you're interested in optimization that regression becomes redundant. I can't see any justification for that principle.

Comment: All regression work is based on optimization (hidden or not). Least-square regression is only one of the infinitely many possible objective functions.

Comment: That's incorrect again. Not all forms of regression require optimization. For example, median smoothing can be done with or without optimization. And I'm assuming that there are other examples.

Comment: With respect to your new question: what do you mean by "collapse" the terms?

Comment: Linear regression models are generally expressed in such a way that each parameter is separate, even if two or more parameters relate to the same variable. Let's say we have yhat=B0+B1*x+B2*x^2, it can be reformulated as yhat=B0+f(x;B1,B2). Then we would be computing the value of x that minimizes (or maximizes) f.